# NetworkManager Applet is unresponsive and I see 'org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached' errors in ~/.xsession-errors

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, i3-window-manager, notify-osd

I see the following errors in my  ~/.xsession-errors

```
(nm-applet:1122): nm-applet-WARNING **: 11:12:56.101: Failed to show notification: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached
[1342:1937:0821/111259.646185:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I am using i3, with xfce helpers in my status bar to make some thing a bit simpler.

I know that if I start xfce4-notifyd it resolves the issues and fixes the errors in xsession-errors.

```
systemctl --user start xfce4-notifyd

systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-08-21 12:52:28 SAST; 10s ago
 Main PID: 10783 (xfce4-notifyd)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xfce4-notifyd.service
           └─10783 /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd

Aug 21 12:52:28 aaron-pc systemd[1088]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Aug 21 12:52:28 aaron-pc systemd[1088]: Started XFCE notifications service.
```

How do I get xfce4-notifyd to start at startup or at login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much reading I found the following sources helped me with this simple solution

```
sudo vim /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.Notification.service

[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

You might what to look and see what other notification services have been configured in dbus.

```
ls /usr/share/dbus-1/services/ | grep -i noti
org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service
org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service
```

And if you have some other notification service already configured which can cause issues with both of them try to start.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service
```

In my case using Manjaro which is a flavour of arch. My setup was a bit different.

The path the executable was in a different place.

```
pacman -Ql xfce4-notifyd | grep 'xfce4-notifyd$'
xfce4-notifyd /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

My exec line looks like this

```
Exec=/usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
```

Additionally, the `xfce4-notifyd` service needs to be started

```
systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

systemctl --user start xfce4-notifyd

systemctl --user status xfce4-notifyd
● xfce4-notifyd.service - XFCE notifications service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-03-10 08:34:10 SAST; 5s ago
Main PID: 7991 (xfce4-notifyd)
CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/xfce4-notifyd.service
        └─7991 /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd

Mar 10 08:34:10 aaron-pc systemd[1456]: Starting XFCE notifications service...
Mar 10 08:34:10 aaron-pc systemd[1456]: Started XFCE notifications service.
```

To ensure that this happens at startup. I add the following

```
cd ~/.config/systemd/user/
ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/user/xfce4-notifyd.service
```

- https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12213
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1471560#c23
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xfce4-notifyd-gtk3-the-notification-service-is-not-running-solved/60627/17

Comment: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11382 that was another link I found some useful info on how to fix my problems